# Sprite not displaying in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a class in my game that tells a sprite to spawn, this class is a `MovieClip` with code attached to it. I call the `spawn()` function on this class and draw the sprite using the graphics API for it. The spawn function is as follows:

```
public function spawn(){
        this.addChild(window)
        window.x = 5
        window.y = 10
        window.width = this.width - 10
        window.height = this.height - 10
        window.graphics.clear()
        window.graphics.drawRect(5, 10, this.width - 10, this.height - 20)
        window.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1)
        trace(window.visible)
}
```

The problem is that child `window` doesn't appear, despite the `visible` trace returning `true`. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
window.graphics.clear()
window.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1)
window.graphics.drawRect(5, 10, this.width - 10, this.height - 20)
window.graphics.endFill();
```

And make sure the class that you add this `window` is also on the stage.